# ERRORS: java.io.FileNotFoundException: args[0]

Tags: java, eclipse

It is the code from HitHub for my learning purpose. And I tried run it in eclipse and got errors like following:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.matsim.core.utils.io.UncheckedIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: args[0]
    at org.matsim.core.utils.io.IOUtils.getBufferedReader(IOUtils.java:125)
    at org.matsim.core.utils.io.IOUtils.getBufferedReader(IOUtils.java:72)
    at org.matsim.core.utils.io.MatsimXmlParser.parse(MatsimXmlParser.java:147)
    at org.matsim.core.config.ConfigUtils.loadConfig(ConfigUtils.java:59)
    at test1.RunCarsharing.main(RunCarsharing.java:23)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: args[0]
... 5 more
```

And the main program is as following:

```
public class RunCarsharing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger.getLogger( "org.matsim.core.controler.Injector" ).setLevel(Level.OFF);

        final Config config = ConfigUtils.loadConfig(args[0]);
        CarsharingUtils.addConfigModules(config);

        final Scenario sc = ScenarioUtils.loadScenario(config);

        final Controler controler = new Controler( sc );

        installCarSharing(controler);

        controler.run();
    }

    public static void installCarSharing(final Controler controler) {
        Scenario sc = controler.getScenario() ;

        controler.addOverridingModule( new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            public void install() {
                this.addPlanStrategyBinding("RandomTripToCarsharingStrategy").to( RandomTripToCarsharingStrategy.class ) ;
                this.addPlanStrategyBinding("CarsharingSubtourModeChoiceStrategy").to( CarsharingSubtourModeChoiceStrategy.class ) ;
            }
        });

        controler.addOverridingModule(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            public void install() {
                bindMobsim().toProvider( CarsharingQsimFactory.class );
            }
        });

        controler.setTripRouterFactory(CarsharingUtils.createTripRouterFactory(sc));

        //setting up the scoring function factory, inside different scoring functions are set-up
        controler.setScoringFunctionFactory(new CarsharingScoringFunctionFactory( sc.getConfig(), sc.getNetwork()));

        final CarsharingConfigGroup csConfig = (CarsharingConfigGroup) controler.getConfig().getModule(CarsharingConfigGroup.GROUP_NAME);
        controler.addControlerListener(new CarsharingListener(controler,
            csConfig.getStatsWriterFrequency() ) ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) I don't think that is the real error message.  I think you have "massaged" it.  2) The program is supposed to be run with at least one command line argument that is pathname for a config file.  My guess is that you gave it an incorrect command line argument.  `FileNotFoundException` means that Java could not find the file that you (the program) asked it to open.

Comment: Is it related to the import files? I have some import files in the reference library which is .class files.

Comment: Java imports?  No.  If a ".class" file is missing when you are loading classes, you will get a different exception.

Answer (score 0):

If the code and stacktrace are accurate, then the only way you can get that exception message is if something is trying to open a file whose filename is `"args[0]"`.